# Azure Cloud Bash Shell file storage 5 GB file downloaded but unable to mount/open

Tags: bash, azure, azure-storage-files

I want to download folders from Azure Cloud Bash Shell.
For this I went to the storage account of the azure cloud shell and located a 5 GB .img file.
The full location to access the file is as follows.

https://csg10032000b5360942.file.core.windows.net/cs-rajat-agrawal-kpitd365-onmicrosoft-com-10032000b5360942/.cloudconsole/acc_rajat.img

(The URL needs my access token to be downloaded.)

I downloaded the file in Windows 10 but upon right click and mount it gives the error "The disc image file is corrupted".
Also I am unable to open the file using WinRar, 7-Zip.

Regards

Rajat Agrawal

Comment: Is there anything unexpected in the answer? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it.

Comment: Don't you need help? I didn't see any response from you. So you just come to copy the solution and give no reply?!

Answer (score 0):

To download the files from the Azure Cloud Shell, it's not a good way to download the image directly. You can change a more appropriate place to store the files or create the folders and then you can download them directly. This place is in the path `/home/user/clouddrive`. When you create the files or folder in this place, it shows like this in the file storage of the Azure Cloud Shell:

[image]

Well, in this situation, you can download them as you want from the file storage, not the image.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling, I managed to open and check contents.

Just add it VDI extension and open it with 7-Zip

[image: IMG image opened as VDI with 7-Zip]